# how to change the color of status bar in flutter when we are using dark/light theme?

Tags: flutter, dart

[Duplicate].I am trying to change the color of status bar through out the app by using the below code in main but i am not able set it to different color when theme is dark. Now I have set it to white but I want black when it is dark theme. This is repeated question but I am not able to get it which is answered earlier as some of them are using some packages which are discontinued and in some they are doing it in each screen where they are using Appbar. Able to do this way with earlier answers but how to change it when theme changes.

I have tried this also:- statusBareColor:themeProvider.isDarkMode? black :white, but this shows error.

```
 class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
 @override
Widget build(BuildContext context) => ChangeNotifierProvider(

create:(context) => ThemeProvider(),
builder:(context,_){
  SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle(
    statusBarColor:white,
  ));
  final themeProvider = Provider.of<ThemeProvider>(context,listen: true);
  return MaterialApp(

    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    themeMode: themeProvider.thememode,
    theme: MyThemes.lightTheme,
    darkTheme: MyThemes.darkTheme,
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

i think you have to use this code on Build function and out of ChangeNotifierProvider, please check it.

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
 @override
Widget build(BuildContext context) { 
SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle(
    statusBarColor:white,
  ));
  return ChangeNotifierProvider(

create:(context) => ThemeProvider(),
builder:(context,_){
  
  final themeProvider = Provider.of<ThemeProvider>(context,listen: true);
  return MaterialApp(

    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    themeMode: themeProvider.thememode,
    theme: MyThemes.lightTheme,
    darkTheme: MyThemes.darkTheme,
    )};
```

Comment: can you please use stateFullWidget and let me know the result?

Comment: still the same result.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `Brightness` property of `AppBar` widget

```
Brightness.light
Brightness.dark
```

in your ThemeData set `appBarTheme` as below

```
MaterialApp(
   theme: ThemeData( 
      appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
        brightness: Brightness.dark, // set dark of light
      ),
    ),
  ),
```

You can change `brightness` with the help of any state management provider

or you can use something like this, put this in your `build` method

```
SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle.light);
```

Comment: I have used this only which u mentioned below, but my question. is how to change it when it is dark theme? and I want to do it in main so that it does through out the app.

Comment: I've edited my question, Kindly take a look

Comment: This is changing the color of bottom nav background, and no difference in status Bar

Comment: Kindly check the last one in answer. I have edited.

Comment: this keep light only even when switches to dark theme

Comment: You can may be handle this by creating a global variable for singltone or any state management